# jquery ajax overlay covers only half of screen

Tags: jquery, ajax, zend-framework, overlay

While doing the classic `$.ajax(...)` call, the overlay appears on screen, but when I scroll down the page, the overlay doesn't cover the entire page.

What do I do to make all ajax initiated overlays to appear correctly?

EDIT:

here's the code:

```
<script type="text/css">
.overlay {
   position: fixed;
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function (){

    $('a.trigger').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: href,
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                'somekey' : 'value'
            }});
        .done(function(data){
            // do something
        });

    });
});
</script>
```

EDIT2:

I forgot to mention it is under Zend Framework.

Answer (score 1):

You can set in css

```
.overlay {
   position: fixed;
}
```

or change position on scroll event

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $('.overlay').css({top: $('body').prop('scrollTop')+'px'})
});
```

on some browsers you will need to use `window` instead of `'body'`

Comment: @phpworker `position: fixed` don't work in old or all IE, so you need to use `position: absolute` and change top on scroll.

Comment: both are not making any change. I am using Chromium and FF v21.0 on ubuntu 12.04 LTS. 
It seems this must something in Zend app, as it has some huge js script files. I thought if it is something easy to overcome, but seems not. I searched it for .overlay but nothing... and I cannot publish whole code. :(

Comment: It seems this must be something in Zend app, as it has some huge js script files. I thought if it is something easy to overcome, but seems not. I found some plugins included: jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.js, jquery.colorbox2.js, jquery.alerts.js, jquery.simplemodal.js, container-min.js - maybe there are simmilar issues known with these plugins?

Comment: OK, this actually worked:

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        $('.ui-front').css({top: $('body').prop('scrollTop')+'px'})
    });

overlay is being scrolled with page, but it doesn't look pretty.Also when overlay appears it is located at the top of the page, even if I am at the bottom. How to overcome this?

Comment: @phpworker why you don't use `.ui-front { position: fixed; }`. and a question do have css file for jquery ui?

Comment: already tried both your propositions also with `.ui-front`... yes, there it is: jquery-ui-1.8.11.green.css

Comment: Found it! this worked for me: `.ui-widget-overlay { position: fixed;}`  - tested on FF and Chromium. Thanks!